# Como aceptar mensaje emergente de Edge en modo IE Python - Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, internet-explorer, edge

Cuanto intento descargar un archivo desde el Edge en modo IE, me aparece un mensaje de confirmacion para esta descarga y no se como superarla, no me permite aceptar comando como ALT + G,  no importa en si el archivo, ya que lo que importaria es superar este paso de aceptar (Guardar) o en su defecto alguna configuracion que permita descargar sin este mensaje

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Ie(service=Service(executable_path="C:\IEDriverServer_Win32_4.14.0\IEDriverServer.exe"))
driver.get("https://www.winrar.es/descargas")
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[contains(text(),"Descargue WinRAR ahora")]").click()
```

Ya intente enviando

```
actions = ActionChains(driver)
actions.key_down(Keys.ALT).send_keys('g').key_up(Keys.ALT).perform()
```

pero no funciona, al igual enviandolo directo por js y tampoco

Comment: La respuesta corta: **no puedes**. La razón: por seguridad JS sólo puede interactuar dentro del documento abierto en la ventana, pero no puede interactuar con elementos del navegador que no son parte del documento, como lo son las ventanas de impresión, guardar archivos y otras. Tal vez podrías ajustar las propiedades de internet referentes a los niveles de seguridad del navegador, para que no pregunte por la descarga de ciertos elementos, como archivos ejecutables.